# How to download efficiently intraday data with Bloomberg API?

Tags: programming, bloomberg

I'm downloading intraday bar data using  Bloomberg API and C#.

I have adapted the official Bloomberg c# "IntradayBarExample” to suit my needs.

However downloads are *really* slow, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6127236/3205529) recommending  to use a dedicated `EventQueue` instead of calling `NextEvent()` on a `Session` object. But the improvement is not really detectable.

As illustration, you can download the 5Min Bar – Best Bid Event- of the last 100 days for AAL UW Equity ticker, it takes very long time to obtain at the end not so much data (< 1Mo).

Did you face the same problem ?

Comment: using an EventQueue synchronizes the response and I don't think it will improve performance much. What would probably improve your throughput is to run requests in parallel (in several threads)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by assylias I have modified my code to run requests in several threads. In case you need to do so, these are some valuable informations :

1- Create a thread-safe request procedure and assign differents `requestID` to your requests. Pass these arguments to `processResponseEvent` via the `eventloop` function. This will allow you to make a check regarding the message you are receiving by using a simple condition:

```
            if (msg.CorrelationID != requestID)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("WRONG ID ");
                return;
            }
```

2- Make your request in parallel, meaning you enclosed the aforementioned  request in a loop such as :

```
     WaitHandle[] waitHandles = new WaitHandle[numOfThreads];
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++)
        {
            var j = i;
            var handle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
            var thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                 /// CALL HERE YOU REQUEST PROCEDURE FROM STEP 1

                handle.Set();
            });
            waitHandles[j] = handle;
            thread.Start();
        }
        foreach (var ee in waitHandles)
            ee.WaitOne();
```

At the end it won't increase the waiting time for each request but since your are performing a bunch of them together you'll still save a LOT of time.

Ps: you can use the variable `i` (from  `for (int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++)`) as  `requestID`.